# Automatically trust URLs via Swift to prevent SSL errors

Tags: swift, macos, http, alamofire, keychain

I have an application that can send HTTP requests (It uses Alamofire to achieve this). The problem I have is that the URL I'm using isn't secure, it is our company API for connected devices.

At the moment the user has to manually visit the API and trust it, then add a random certificate to keychain... Not very elegant.

I've created my own `SessionManager : Alamofire.SessionManager` and used `.disableEvaluation` on the URL, it is listed in the `info.plist` under `App Transport Security Settings -> Exception Domains`. All correctly formatted to the best of my knowledge. None of it prevents to user having to manually visit the site to trust it.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Create correct certificates on backend side...

Comment: @SergeyDi Not an option unfortunately

Comment: What specific error do you get when you call the site using Alamofire?

Comment: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made